# Double Sound in jwplayer jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

Hi I used to play video using jwplayer jquery plugin. its working fine in Mozilla browser.
When i play the same video in chrome i listen double sound.i refresh the browser and clear the cashes and cookies.

Did any solution for chrome browser

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//<![CDATA[
//setpopuptime = setpopuptime + 15000;//15 sec

var flashvars = { file:encodeURIComponent(c('<?php echo base64_encode($audio_full_path); ?>')),autostart:'true' };
var params = { allowfullscreen:'false', allowscriptaccess:'always' };
var attributes = { id:'player1', name:'player1' };
swfobject.embedSWF('<?php echo ROOT.$this->webroot; ?>jwplayer/player.swf','container1','1024','600','9.0.115','false',flashvars, params, attributes, flashLoaded);

function flashLoaded(e) {
    jwplayer(e.ref).onPlay(function() { 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        jwplayer(e.ref).pause();
        window.parent.checkmefirst(); }, setpopuptime);
});
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide an example to look at.

Comment: Please check the above code

Comment: The code looks like it should work (though I'd probably clear your timeout inside your onPlay listener, just so you don't potentially double up on your pop-ups, but that's an aside) it may be an issue with flash in your chrome (try another comp) or it may be an issue with the video (codec maybe?).